# How can I generate same GUID for one subscriber with multiple records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a `table` called `member` with 4 columns `memberid` (it's a `GUID column`), `subscriber key` (will be same for both subscriber and dependent), `First name` (it contains first name of subscriber and his dependents) and `Last name` (it contains last name of subscriber and his dependents).

Currently I'm getting the unique `GUID` values for all the records, for eg: if there are 4 records in the table, 2 records for the `member` and 2 records for the dependent, the `GUID` value is different for all the 4 records.

But I need same `GUID` value for 2 member records and another `GUID` value for the dependent records. Please let me know how to get this in SQL Server.

Comment: Please show us some data which demonstrates what you are trying to do here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
--Test data
create table #temp_table  (col1 uniqueidentifier , co12 uniqueidentifier , col3 uniqueidentifier);

--use variable save the guid,when insert use it
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier  
SET @guid = NEWID() ;
insert into #temp_table (col1,co12,col3) values (@guid,@guid,@guid);

--result
select * from #temp_table;
```

[image]

hope help you : )